# Creating a plant health classifier using machine learning

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, feature-extraction, supervised-learning

First time poster so please be gentle.

As the title suggests, I am planning to create a generic (i.e. each instance can detect a plant of one type) plant health classifier by using supervised machine learning which utilises images of healthy and unhealthy plants. The metrics would be the colour of the leaves, shape and the presence of any fungi on any part of the plant.

I've dabbled with machine learning before and written up a program for facial recognition using the Eigenfaces method and classification using the Knn method, but am still a newbie nonetheless. I'm no math genius, so any intuitive explanation would be greatly appreciated.

This being said, I would like to perform the same thing, but for plants, and would like to respectfully ask a few things, as noted in the square brackets below. As this project will definitely take some time, I would like to see if my thought process is correct.

My intended steps (correct me if I'm wrong) are as follows:

1. Obtain *loads* of controlled images (e.g. Leaves only, no
   background)
2. Normalise the images change the images to grayscale. [1]
3. Ensure the dimensions are the same
4. Feature Extraction? [2]
5. Label and feed into machine learning algorithm [3]
6. Insert an image, repeat steps 2-4 feed into machine learning algorithm and label pops out.

Hence, my questions are as follows:

1. Will normalisation or conversion to grayscale cause a loss in features of an image?
2. If I'm using just the Knn method, will this be necessary? If so, will this be the basis of my machine learning algorithm?
3. Will I still be able to use Eigenfaces method for a plant and produce results of similar accuracy to if I were to perform Eigenfaces on faces? Otherwise, what type of algorithm should I use?
4. Is there anything that I might have missed out on that I should be aware of?

My apologies for the long post. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the solutions from the recently completed [Kaggle Competition on Diabetic Retinopathy Detection](https://www.kaggle.com/c/diabetic-retinopathy-detection). 
The problem seems to be similar to yours, image processing and identifying spots inside the images.

[This blog post](http://jeffreydf.github.io/diabetic-retinopathy-detection/) by Top-10-finisher Jeffrey De Fauw has an excellent write-up and the python source code is [available](https://github.com/JeffreyDF/kaggle_diabetic_retinopathy) .

This does not answer your questions (instead it refers to your "intended steps"), and maybe the algorithm(s) he used is not right for you, but maybe you can get a glimpse of the general strategy, at least of the image-preprocessing workflow.

Comment: Thanks @knb! What you suggested does seem like a good place for me to start on things. The problem does indeed seem quite similar to the leaf one as you mentioned. I'll look into the source code and see if this works with my dataset, which I will acquire in a bit.